# Remove previous history of uploaded files

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am facing problem whenever i run a program.Whenever i upload a file and press add, next to add button, the name of the uploaded file will be appeared and that's what i wanted too.But when i run again without doing clean and build, previously uploaded file names are not erased. They are still displaying the old names.But if i press clean and build and run the program it erases the previous upload names.I want it without clean and build every time..or else auto clean and build when i press run.Is it possible??

Comment: Do you have Any code?

Comment: Hi i tried to post the code for long time but its showing some error while posting so just posted the message..Any other alternative to post the message? @Kitex

Comment: error while posting code?  what kind of??

Comment: its showing error like "code is not formatted properly"..Anyway bro problem solved.Thanks a lot for your kindness :)